# OData query over DbGeometry attribute using $filter=geo.distance

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, geometry, odata

Ok guys, I'm using OData v4 and WebApi 2.2 with some entities having DbGeometry properties set in coordinate system 4674.
Lets assume we have a simple entity like as follow:

```
public class Aerodrome
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry Location { get; set; }
}
```

And a simple ODataController as follow:

```
public class AerodromeController : ODataController
{

    private SqlDbContext Db

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        Db = new SqlDbContext();
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Aerodrome> Get()
    {
        return Db.Aerodrome;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Store.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

And the WebApiConfig set like this

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Aerodrome>("Aerodrome");
    config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", null, builder.GetEdmModel());
}
```

Now, almost everything looks nice. I can use OData queries like host/Aerodrome?$filter=startswith(Name, 'Flor')") or host/Aerodrome?$top=20&$skip=60" and I get the expected result set.

However, I just can make a filter work sith a geo.* filter.

host/Aerodrome?$filter=geo.distance(Location, POINT (-72.768952 -7.599057)) lt 900.0

It returns error as follow:

```
"error":{
"code":"","message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. ')' or ',' expected at position 59 in 'geo.distance(Localizacao,geography, Point(-122.03547668457 47.6316604614258)) lt 900'.","innererror":{
  "message":"')' or ',' expected at position 59 in 'geo.distance(Localizacao,geography, Point(-122.03547668457 47.6316604614258)) lt 900'.","type":"Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataException","stacktrace":"   em Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.FunctionCallParser.ParseArgumentList()\r\n
```

Someone can enlighten what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like it's complaining about the space between the values in the Point, perhaps it needs a comma or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The geo functions are not implemented in odata V4. you can add the support yourself but it is a bit complex solution involving changing oData code itself.

The solution is explained here  [Dealing with spatial data in OData](https://medium.com/@nirinchev/dealing-with-spatial-data-in-odata-4e4051434ddb#.bo8ormhcj)

Comment: as well as V3 for web api project.